# It is illegal to vandalize public places in Europe?

Tags: european-union, travel, vandalism

For instance, if a fountain in Rome is vandalized by e.g. throwing acid in the water, is this illegal?

Comment: Yes and probably much more. Risk to public health ; compensation of all costs for damages/repairs etc.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, obviously.

For example, a tourist was recently charged with vandalism after [carving his name into a wall of the Colosseum](https://www.lbc.co.uk/news/british-tourist-rome-colosseum-carving-ivan-hayley-into-brick-prosecutor/).

Comment: Unsurprisingly, this is also a crime in Israel. https://www.cnn.com/travel/article/tourist-smashes-statues-israel-scli-intl/index.html

Answer (score 3):

> It is illegal to vandalize public places in Europe?

Yes.

> For instance, if a fountain in Rome is vandalized by e.g. throwing
> acid in the water, is this illegal?

Yes.